# Recyclerview items text look different on different devices

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I am working on an activity that has three recyclerviews.

My issue is that the output is different on different devices.

I am testing the app on my real device and on the Android Studio emulators, and the output is right. But I have some customers users who say that the output is wrong.

Here is my screen shot with the right output:

[image]

And this is the wrong output on some devices:

[image]

I have tried changing text size, but with no success.

I ask you where should I start looking for a solution, at recyclerview or at item view?

EDIT

Activity Layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"

    android:background="#f2f2f2">



    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/cabeceraTicket"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/cardview_dark_background"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtTicket"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Ticket: "
            android:textColor="@color/cardview_light_background"
            android:textSize="18sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtSalon"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Salón: "
            android:textColor="@color/cardview_light_background"
            android:textSize="18sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtMesa"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Mesa:"
            android:textColor="@color/cardview_light_background"
            android:textSize="18sp" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/botones"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/cabeceraTicket"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnTodo"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Menu/Ticket" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnMenu"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Menu" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnTicket"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Ticket" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/botones2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/botones"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnRegresar"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#009688"
            android:text="Salir"
            android:textColor="@color/white" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnMarchar"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#3F51B5"
            android:text="Marchar todo"
            android:textColor="@color/white" />


    </LinearLayout>
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnConectar"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button"
        android:visibility="gone" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/menus"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/botones2"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView3"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:text="Menú"
            android:textSize="24sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/lmenu1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/l0"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:src="@android:drawable/ic_media_previous" />

            <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/recyclerViewMenu0"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="10"
                android:orientation="horizontal">


            </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/r0"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:src="@android:drawable/ic_media_next" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/lmenu2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:visibility="visible">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/l1"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:src="@android:drawable/ic_media_previous" />

            <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/recyclerViewMenu1"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="10"
                android:orientation="horizontal">


            </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/r1"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:src="@android:drawable/ic_media_next" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/lmenu3"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="80dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:visibility="visible">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/l2"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:src="@android:drawable/ic_media_previous" />

            <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/recyclerViewArticulos1"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="10"
                android:orientation="horizontal">


            </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/r2"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:src="@android:drawable/ic_media_next" />
        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/ticket"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/menus"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/titulo"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView4"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:text="Ticket"
                android:textSize="24sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <ListView
                android:id="@+id/listview"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_below="@+id/titulo"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                android:listSelector="@drawable/list_selector"
                android:state_activated="true" />
        </LinearLayout>


    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

First recyclerview item layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_margin="1dp">

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        app:cardCornerRadius="4dp"
        app:cardElevation="1dp"
        app:cardMaxElevation="2dp">


        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/relative"
            android:layout_width="120dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical">


            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/name"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

                    android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                    android:layout_weight="4"
                    android:autoSizeMaxTextSize="15sp"
                    android:autoSizeMinTextSize="8sp"
                    android:autoSizeTextType="uniform"
                    android:gravity="center|center_horizontal|center_vertical"
                    android:padding="12dp"
                    android:text="Canada"
                    android:textAllCaps="false"
                    android:textColor="@color/red_A700"
                    android:textSize="30sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    app:autoSizeMinTextSize="20sp"
                    app:fontFamily="sans-serif" />

            </LinearLayout>

        </RelativeLayout>

    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Second recyclerview item layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_margin="1dp">

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        app:cardCornerRadius="4dp"
        app:cardElevation="1dp"
        app:cardMaxElevation="2dp">


        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/relative"
            android:layout_width="120dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical">


            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/name"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"

                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                android:autoSizeMaxTextSize="15sp"
                android:autoSizeMinTextSize="8sp"
                android:autoSizeTextType="uniform"
                android:gravity="center|center_horizontal|center_vertical"
                android:padding="12dp"
                android:text="Canada"
                android:textAllCaps="false"
                android:textColor="@color/red_A700"
                android:textSize="30sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                app:autoSizeMinTextSize="20sp"
                app:fontFamily="sans-serif" />

        </RelativeLayout>

    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Third recyclerview item layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_margin="1dp">

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        app:cardCornerRadius="4dp"
        app:cardElevation="1dp"
        app:cardMaxElevation="2dp">


        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/relative"
            android:layout_width="120dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical">


            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/name"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"

                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                android:autoSizeMaxTextSize="15sp"
                android:autoSizeMinTextSize="8sp"
                android:autoSizeTextType="uniform"
                android:gravity="center|center_horizontal|center_vertical"
                android:padding="12dp"
                android:text="Canada"
                android:textAllCaps="false"
                android:textColor="@color/red_A700"
                android:textSize="30sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                app:autoSizeMinTextSize="20sp" />

        </RelativeLayout>

    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: pls update your layout xml file here

Comment: @HiteshTarbundiya, sure

Comment: @HiteshTarbundiya, done

Comment: @mvasco Add a Scroll View there for main view

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your code contain like this,

```
    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/relative"
        android:layout_width="120dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"></>
```

you need to change the item layout fixed length width

Comment: I will try it, let me check it with other devices.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest not to set values for the textsize in your xml at all (either in `dp` or `sp`). Let each user **choose** their preferred textSize by changing the system-wide font size in the device's `Settings--->Display--->FontSize`.

Just make sure any container for these textViews (the parent layout of each textView) can accommodate textViews of varying sizes. One way this can be accomplished, is by setting the container's width and height values to '`WrapContent`' if possible.

My answer should be viewed like a shift in your approach to text sizes in general, rather than a specific answer to a specific problem like the one you are facing. There may well be easier and faster solutions if you just want to **quick-fix** your current issue.

Comment: You are welcome. On the long run you will find that this approach is more user friendly.